# Is 'With your email' effective copy for a mix of social and local log in options?

Tags: login, social

We're designing an application that requires you to sign in before you can use it. Upon launch, you're presented with two options:

- Sign up
- Log in

Selecting either will give you the option to use social sign up/in (facebook and twitter) or create an account/log in with your account.

We're struggling with the wording for the local account option...

For sign up we have:

- Facebook
- Twitter
- Create account

For sign in we have:

- With Facebook
- With Twitter
- With my account

I've also seen the copy 'With your email' a lot, but there are concerns that people won't get it. At the same time I think 'With my account' is pretty obscure as well.

What are the best practices when it comes a sign up/in flow like this. Any tried and tested copy to recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just **'with my [service name] account'**? It removes ambiguity as to what exactly the account is for, and makes it obvious that this is a local login option. 'With my email' is common, but I think your concerns are valid - I've encountered some who get confused and think they're signing into their email account instead.

Answer (score 1):

At my company, enthuse.me, we use a form for the 'enthuse account'/e-mail login and 3 buttons for the social logins, separated on the page.

[image]

If you look at [enthuse.me/signups](http://www.enthuse.me/signups) (our sign up page) you'll see we have a similar separation for creating an account with e-mail address or social. In our usability testing so far, no one has been confused by this choice, with about half the participants choosing e-mail and the other half going for one of the social logins. We haven't tested a login page with a button instead of the form, but our assumption is that adding the extra click/step is unnecessary, since there doesn't seem to be any confusion currently.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the user chooses "Log in" at the first level, it should be necessary to include 'with' at the second level. Just as you haven't included it in the first condition, "Sign in" in your example above.

For input labels "Email" or "Email or Username" are common.

Upon arriving at a log in or sign up opportunity, you'll see more log in forms w/ a link to register/sign up for established portals.

It would be wise to flip this to a register/sign up form w/ a link to log in for new services.

Comment: I have seen many of the examples where the social sign in options are provided next to the sign up or log in form. It results in quite a crowded view so I was hoping to isolate them and only provide the user with a form if he's actually about to use it.